# SilverStripe GraphQL - Syntax Error

Tags: php, graphql, silverstripe-4

I'm attempted to scaffold a basic DataObject into the schema, but my queries are throwing the following errors:

http://localhost:8080/graphql:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:1) Unexpected <EOF>\n\n1: \n   ^\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And, http://localhost:8080/graphql/?query={readQuickPossessions{ID+Title+Address+SquareFeet}}:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:25) Cannot parse the unexpected character \"+\".\n\n1: {readQuickPossessions{ID+Title+Address+SquareFeet}}\n                           ^\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the DataObject:

```
<?php
namespace Trigger\HomeBuilderSite\DataObjects;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\GraphQL\Scaffolding\Interfaces\ScaffoldingProvider;
use SilverStripe\GraphQL\Scaffolding\Scaffolders\SchemaScaffolder;

class QuickPossession extends DataObject implements ScaffoldingProvider {
  private static $table_name = 'QuickPossession';

  private static $db = [
    'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'Address' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'SquareFeet' => 'Int',
  ];

  private static $has_one = [];

  public function provideGraphQLScaffolding(SchemaScaffolder $scaffolder) {
    $scaffolder
      ->type(QuickPossession::class)
        ->addFields([
          'ID', 
          'Title',
          'Address', 
          'SquareFeet'
        ])
        ->operation(SchemaScaffolder::READ)
          ->end()
        ->operation(SchemaScaffolder::UPDATE)
          ->end()
        ->end();
    return $scaffolder;
  }
}
```

And in mysite.yml:

```
SilverStripe\GraphQL\Controller:
  schema:
    scaffolding_providers:
      - Trigger\HomeBuilderSite\DataObjects\QuickPossession
```

Any insights into what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've responded to the ticket. Issue appears to be an invalid query. By default, the read operations have pagination.

```
query {
  readQuickPosessions {
    edges {
       node {
         ID
         Title
       }
    }
    pageInfo {
       hasNextPage
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can turn off pagination with `->setUsePagination(false)` on the operation node.

You can use [silverstripe graphql devtools](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql-devtools) to debug this as well.

Comment: thanks for answering on both the issue and StackOverflow!

Comment: I was missing *edges* and *node* in my query. Issue addressed and closed [here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql/issues/140)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query that silverstripe-graphql is producing is incorrect:

```
{readQuickPossessions{ID+Title+Address+SquareFeet}}
```

There is no `+` [syntax in GraphQL queries](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/)

I would recommend trying [the YAML method to scaffold an object](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql#exposing-a-dataobject-to-graphql) and seeing if there's a difference, and potentially there's an update that fixes this.

If that doesn't work, and you've checked all the syntax, you should definitely [report an issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql/issues).

Comment: Just tried the YAML method for scaffolding. Is it possible there's another issue at play since even an empty query to the /graphql endpoint results in an error? It seems like `+` syntax shouldn't be a problem in that case.

I'll follow up with an issue.

Comment: @JustinTBrown that could be the case

Comment: Issue opened here: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql/issues/140